Upgraded from Angular 12 to Angular 18 and now components loaded from lazy loaded module not being removed on page navigation due to animations
I have this following module
enter image description here
And I have it lazy load on a route like so
{
        path: 'configuration/roles',
        loadChildren: () => import('gizmonic-features-angular').then(f => f.ConfigurationRolesModule)
    },

The problem I am running into though is when I navigate and come back a few times it is just appending the components not removing the old and adding the new one. This was working fine in Angular 12 so not sure what the issue could be.
I don't use any standalone components either so doesn't seem like a conflict that I have seen in some other posts.
enter image description here
I've tried a few things and nothing has really helped. Have been unable to find any real discussion about this issue anywhere
Edit 1:
Come to find out it looks like this piece of code is causing the issue.
 @Component({
    selector: 'gizmonic-column',
    templateUrl: './column.component.html',
    animations: [
         trigger('fillState', [
             state('on', style({
                 maxWidth: '2000px'
             })),
             state('off', style({
                 maxWidth: '768px'
             })),
             transition('on => off', animate('0.25s ease-in')),
             transition('off => on', animate('0.25s ease-out'))
         ])
    ],
})
export class ColumnComponent {
    @Input()
    @HostBinding('attr.display-mode')
    public displayMode: "focused" | "foreground" | "background" = "foreground";

    @Input()
    public showHeader: boolean = true;

    @Input()
    @HostBinding('attr.header-display-mode')
    headerDisplayMode: "full" | "wrapped" = "full";

    @Input()
    @HostBinding('attr.content-display-mode')
    contentDisplayMode: "full" | "wrapped" | "indented" = "full";

    @Input()
    public fill: boolean = false;

    get fillState() {
        return this.fill ? "on" : "off";
    }

    constructor() {

    }
}

If I remove the animations everything works fine. I can't find out why though those animations started not working in Angular 18.
Edit 2
I have a component that uses animations. now that I have upgraded to Angular 18 when I lazy load a module that contains that component as a part of another component. The animations don't run and it causes the other component to not be unloaded after page naviagion occurs. The component in question is also the component that displays on page load.
@Component({
    selector: 'gizmonic-column',
    templateUrl: './column.component.html',
    animations: [
        trigger('fillState', [
            state('on', style({
                maxWidth: '2000px'
            })),
            state('off', style({
                maxWidth: '768px'
            })),
            transition('on => off', animate('0.25s ease-in')),
            transition('off => on', animate('0.25s ease-out'))
        ])
    ],
})
export class ColumnComponent {
    @Input()
    @HostBinding('attr.display-mode')
    public displayMode: "focused" | "foreground" | "background" = "foreground";

    @Input()
    public showHeader: boolean = true;

    @Input()
    @HostBinding('attr.header-display-mode')
    headerDisplayMode: "full" | "wrapped" = "full";

    @Input()
    @HostBinding('attr.content-display-mode')
    contentDisplayMode: "full" | "wrapped" | "indented" = "full";

    @Input()
    public fill: boolean = false;

    get fillState() {
        return this.fill ? "on" : "off";
    }

    constructor() {

    }
}

I have the BrowserAnimationsModule imported as well. When I remove the animation everything works as expected and the components are removed properly after page navigation. I can's seem to figure out what changed between 12 and 18 that would cause this animation to break the page.
I removed the animation and saw that it no longer kept the component, but now my page doesn't look right because the animation didn't occur

please share a github repo or a stackblitz where the issue happens, require the minimal reproducible code example
